# Avoid moving the map with Overlays

Tags: openlayers-3

Do you know how to avoid panning the map view when showing overlays with OpenLayers 3? I have a popup objects, displaying with hovers or click events. But I'd like to aovid the whole view to move, that can be quite disturbing with many "hover" popups which move the map to show this object...

I guess that will be with the change:position event of ol.Overlay, but what's the function to "block view pan" in this case ?

Comment: do you set the `autoPan` overlay config option to `true`??? Check the api doc http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Overlay.html

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice this option! This is way better. Now I'm trying to change this property after the map and the overlay are defined, but even with `setProperties({autoPan: false})` this has no effect.